# React zoom pan pinch throws a Cannot read property 'limitToWrapper' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i have component that renders a image component with zoom equals to true as a props, inside the Image compo i have react zoom pin panch plugin i wrapp the image with the TransformWrapper compo as said in the documentation and throw a error "Cannot read property 'limitToWrapper' of undefined "

Image compo
[image]

Comment: Which version of `react-zoom-pan-pinch` are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are not passing the required `options` object along to the `<TransformWrapper />` component, that contains the `limitToWrapper` helper.

See the example [in the repo](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/blob/master/example/src/App.js#L80):

```js
<TransformWrapper
  options={{
    limitToBounds,
    transformEnabled,
    disabled,
    limitToWrapper,
  }},
  ...
>
  <img ... />
</TransformWrapper>
```

You can also check [this issue](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/issues/74) if you are on a version lower than 1.6.1.